# Is there a way to check Premiere's date and time via YouTube API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there a way to check Premiere's date and time?

User can upload video to YouTube and schedule its first run. It can be done by setting a video as Premiere -> https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9080341?hl=en

I would like to know the time and date when a video will be "live"; when I can actually watch it.

I can't find any parameter in `/videos` or `/search` that could help.

Only `liveStreamingDetails` or `eventType=upcoming` belongs to category of what I search for but they don't provide information about date and time.

Best,

Comment: What do you mean by Premiere's date?   YouTube is just a video hosting service.  You would possibly find the date the video was uploaded.

Comment: Hello @DalmTo, thank you for your comment. I edited my post to be more specific, maybe it helps with explanation of what I mean by Premiere's date.